# Как вывести легенду через plt.legend()

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, matplotlib, seaborn

Как вывести легенду через `plt.legend()`?
Не используя `Legend=True`, в самом `histplot`, потому что тогда создаётся легенда для каждого элемента `ax`, а нужна общая легенда для `figure`).

Легенда должна быть точно такая же как если бы в `sns.histplot()` добавить параметр `Legend=True`, т.е. легенда рисуется по значению `hue`. 
Но с той оговоркой что она должна быть одна.

А так получается из-за того, что `sns.histplot()` строится в цикле то и легенды получается **`3`**.

Выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> No handles with labels found to put in legend.

---

**main.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Q" : [5, 5, 1, 8, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 3],
             "Total_traffic": [775.48846,
                              861.96324,
                              261.1186,
                              179.18564,
                              351.99208,
                              416.67461,
                              448.88413,
                              550.44581,
                              783.64464,
                              455.97369],
                  "Downlink": [360.13,
                                3023.54,
                                790.96,
                                2590.97,
                                731.61,
                                1346.89,
                                438.27,
                                3428.69,
                                1786.99,
                                610.43]})

feature = ["Q", "Total_traffic", "Downlink"]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(20,15))

counter = 0
for i in range(3):
        sns.histplot(data=df, x=feature[counter], hue="Q", multiple="stack", bins=100, legend=False,
                      ax=ax[i])
        counter+=1
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.suptitle('Распределение численных данных', y=1.05, fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: А **что именно** вы хотите видеть в легенде? Не очень понятно.

Comment: Легенда должна быть точно такая же как если бы в sns.histplot() добавить параметр Legend=True, т.е. легенда рисуется по значению hue. Но с той оговоркой что она должна быть одна. А так получается из-за того что sns.histplot() строится в цикле то и легенды получается 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Q" : [5, 5, 1, 8, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 3],
    "Total_traffic": [
        775.48846,
        861.96324,
        261.1186,
        179.18564,
        351.99208,
        416.67461,
        448.88413,
        550.44581,
        783.64464,
        455.97369],
    "Downlink": [
        360.13,
        3023.54,
        790.96,
        2590.97,
        731.61,
        1346.89,
        438.27,
        3428.69,
        1786.99,
        610.43]
})

feature = ["Q", "Total_traffic", "Downlink"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10, 6))

counter = 0
for i in range(3):
    sns.histplot(
        data=df, 
        x=feature[counter], 
        hue="Q", 
        element="step",     # +++ 
        multiple="stack", 
        bins=100, 
#        legend=False,                              # --- 
        ax=ax[i]
    )
    
    legend = ax[i].get_legend()                     # +++ 
    handles = legend.legendHandles                  # +++ 
    legend.remove()                                 # +++ 

    counter+=1
    
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
ax[i].legend(
    handles, 
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',  '9', '10'], 
    title='Legend Q'
)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, кстати действительно можно, я что-то не подумал) Тогда уж генератор списка добавить вместо перечисления вручную)